# Bokeh + Datashader + Bokeh - Capture Mouse Double Tap

Tags: bokeh, scatter-plot, double-click, holoviews, datashader

I'm implementing a ScatterPlot for Big Data using Bokeh, DataShader and HoloViews. 
The ScatterPlot part itself is pretty much done but there is one requirement I'm having issues with: I need to be able to capture the data coordinates where the user does a  double-click.

I found some code that is working for me in Jupyter notebook, but for some reason, when migrating to Python and Bokeh Server, it doesn't.

Here is the code:

```
    from os.path import dirname, join
import csv

import holoviews as hv
import datashader as ds

import pandas as pd


#import parambokeh
from holoviews.operation.datashader import aggregate, shade, datashade, dynspread
from holoviews.operation import decimate
from holoviews.streams import RangeXY
from holoviews import streams
from bokeh.plotting import curdoc
hv.extension('bokeh')



class MyScatterPlotBokeh:


#
#   PARAMETERS:
#                - keyFieldName    : Field  that uniquely identify a row
#                - xFieldName      : Field Name used for x-Axis
#                - yFieldName      : Field Name used for y-Axis
#                - colorFieldName  : Field Name used to select circle colors
#                - otherFieldNames : Comma separated value variable with the name of all fields we want to show data 
#
    def __init__(self, filePath, title, screenWidth, screenHeight, keyFieldName, xFieldName, yFieldName, colorFieldName, otherFieldNames):


           self._screenHeight = screenHeight
           self._screenWidth  = screenWidth

#  Read data from file
           df = pd.read_csv(filePath)
           df[colorFieldName]=df[colorFieldName].astype("category")

#  Creating graphic
           hover_opts = hv.opts("QuadMesh [tools=['hover']] (alpha=0 hover_alpha=0.2)")            
           self._points = hv.Points(df,kdims=[xFieldName,yFieldName])         
           self._dynamic_hover = datashade(self._points) * dynspread(datashade(self._points, aggregator=ds.count_cat(colorFieldName))) * \
             hv.util.Dynamic(aggregate(self._points, width=50, height=50, streams=[RangeXY]),operation=hv.QuadMesh) 


# Interaction - Point selection
           double_tap = streams.DoubleTap(transient=True, source=self._points)

           self._countTap = 0
           self._taps = []


           def record_taps(x,y):      
               print "clicked"
               self._countTap += 1
               if self._countTap>2: 
                 self._countTap = 0
               if None not in [x,y]:
                  if self._countTap == 1:
                     self._taps.insert(0,(x, y))
                  else:
                     self._taps.append((x, y))
               print "TAPS LOOK LIKE "  + str(self._taps)
               return hv.Points(self._taps, vdims='Taps')


           self._finalPlot = self._dynamic_hover + hv.DynamicMap(record_taps, streams=[double_tap])



    def draw(self):
        hv.renderer('bokeh').server_doc(self._finalPlot)
```

As soon as the server is executed, I can see the "clicked" message showing, but never never after a **double click** on the browser. Is like the **double click** event is not responding.
Eventually I need to send the clicked X & Y coordinates to the browser which I think I can do by create an input box from the python code, but I'm not there yet.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I suspect this is a bug that was recently resolved (see https://github.com/ioam/holoviews/pull/2239). Would you mind trying HoloViews master? We'll try to have a v1.9.3 bug fix release asap.

Comment: I will try that and let you know. Thanks philippjfr

Comment: @philippjfr   Installed last version and now I get this error, sorry but no clue yet why: /anaconda2/envs/ds/lib/python2.7/site-packages/holoviews/operation/datashader.py:386: FutureWarning: xarray.DataArray.__contains__ currently checks membership in DataArray.coords, but in xarray v0.11 will change to check membership in array values.
  if 'x_axis' in agg and 'y_axis' in agg: None of the available storage backends were able to support the supplied data format. XArrayInterface raised following error:
 cannot create a Dataset from a DataArray with the same name as one of its coordinate

Comment: The problem is this line: dynspread(datashade(self._points, aggregator=ds.count_cat(colorFieldName)))
And double_click still does not work :(

Comment: just to be clear current version is: 1.9.2-9-gd2409456f

Comment: The new version 1.9.2 fixed the problem. I had to versions on my machine and I realized I was still pointing to the wrong path.

Answer (score 1):

Using version 1.9.2 fixed the problem as pointed by **philippjfr**

> I suspect this is a bug that was recently resolved (see github.com/ioam/holoviews/pull/2239). Would you mind trying HoloViews master? We'll try to have a v1.9.3 bug fix release asap. – philippjfr